# Use JSONP in cross domain call

Tags: angularjs, json, http

I have a `http` call in AngularJs like this:

```
$http.get("b.example.com/b").then(function1(){show data}, function2(){show error})
```

I am on the `a.example.com/a` domain and getting data from `b.example.com/b`. But I always get `http 500 error`. I think it is because I am doing a cross domain call. When I click `b.example.com/b`, I can see the data. But the data just won't show on `a.example.com/a`.

What can I do if I want to use `JSONP` in this case? Currently, I have no right to modify `b.example.com/b` because I am only working on the front end.

Comment: use `$http.jsonp` instead of `$http.get`.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

Comment: I think if it is a cross domain the browser going to tell you but error 500 means  something went wrong on the called server

Comment: Is other domain even set up to provide jsonp?

Comment: @charlietfl No, I think.

Comment: @AbdelrhmanMohamed I hope this can be a server side bug, but I am not sure.

Comment: well if it's not then you either need to set it up or use a proxy on current domain to get the data. You can't tell server to send jsonp if it isn't set up to serve jsonp

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, thanks. I will talk to back end team if the problem still seems to be caused by cross domain call.

Comment: so if it is your own team, get them to implement CORS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just confirmed that this bug has nothing to do with JSONP, just as Abdelrhman Mohamed said. There is an socket connection exception in the back end.